# No bluetooth found HP 15-da2044ur (RTL8723DE) Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, realtek, realtek-wireless

On Windows, it worked. And it worked on Linux Mint 20 out of the box.
But then something happened. I reinstalled Ubuntu and Linux Mint several times. I tried different drivers, including this https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/realtek.html#ID7

I even tried to install Windows 11, and there it works perfectly. But when I installed Ubuntu back, nothing helps.

Also, I tried to reset BIOS. Unfortunately, have no settings to turn on and off Bluetooth.
Wi-Fi works excellent.

**Now I have fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 Did nothing with drivers**

uname -a

```
Linux fibboo-laptop 5.13.0-37-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 15:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg | grep -i blue gives nothing

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b1 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5009 (rev 01)
```

lspci -k -s 02:00.0

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
Kernel driver in use: rtw_8723de
Kernel modules: rtw88_8723de
```

bluetoothctl

```
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

rfkill list all

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

lsmod | grep rtw

```
rtw88_8723de           16384  0
rtw88_8723d            61440  1 rtw88_8723de
rtw88_pci              24576  1 rtw88_8723de
rtw88_core            200704  2 rtw88_8723d,rtw88_pci
mac80211             1028096  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_core
cfg80211              888832  2 rtw88_core,mac80211
```

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases are available with different stacks; I don't know what Linux Mint 20 is based on (*if it's a LTS release I'm including the stack too; as Ubuntu has ISOs with different stacks*); but I'd look at what that was & what Ubuntu stack was being used, and try using that kernel stack (be it GA, HWE or OEM).  Have you tried the GA stack? as your details match HWE.

Comment: I downloaded iso from here the last LTS version Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I don't know what stack used. And what is stack anyway and how to check it and change?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop ISOs use the HWE stack meaning 5.13 kernel was used with 20.04.4 (5.11 with 20.04.3, 5.8 with 20.04.2 etc).  That is details I'd use to contrast with the Linux Mint you mentioned that you said worked; ie. if Linux Mint was using the GA kernel stack from 20.04 (ie. 5.4 kernel) you can switch your Ubuntu system to use that stack too; an option with Ubuntu LTS releases (Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS installs default to GA).  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  ie. use the Linux Mint works details as clue as to what differs & how to fix it

Comment: I reinstall to Linux Mint today. ISO downloaded from here https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=292
Bluetooth don't notwork, Wi-Fi works as always.

I don't know what is happening. The only idea is that somehow bluetooth is in hardware block, but I did not find any hardware button.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Ubuntu & *flavors* do not use run-time *adjustments*, because code is modified, new packages are built and there is no need (along with the added risk vectors opened security wise by use of *adjustments*). Linux Mint relies on *adjustments* as it allows them to use foreign (Ubuntu) packages and not create everything themselves (it also means many things on Ubuntu that work are different in Linux Mint).  Only Ubuntu and flavors (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here.

Comment: I understand. But the point is that now Bluetooth is not working on any Debian system, and I want to understand why on example of Ubuntu.

Comment: And I installed Mint only for test. Right now I'm back with Ubuntu and have the same problem and have no idea where to dig further.

Comment: For the Mint detail to be useful you'll have to provide specifics as to what's on it.  I can look up details for any Ubuntu ISO, any Debian ISO too - but Linux Mint don't provide specifics of what's on their systems, a link to the manifest for the ISO at a minimum maybe helpful (like Ubuntu & Debian provide). It's the software stack details that can be compared as Ubuntu CLI tools cannot query Linux Mint databases (there are none as Mint doesn't create any, only Debian & Ubuntu provide them!).  You can boot the Linux Mint ISO & get details from there (without install too!)